# Tutorials Using Modals - Libraries and Examples

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I am looking for examples or libraries that use modals as a form of tutorials.  Basically, a user goes to a website for the first time and is guided through a series of modals (or other objects) that outlines the functionality and areas of the web application.  Basically, start with one modal welcoming, then close that to open another to point to some functionality, close that and point to another, rinse and repeat...

I have seen it before, but I can't seem to find any good examples since my search terms seem to bring me to tutorials on how to build modals.  I am looking for a flow of it already out there, or if someone knows of a library designed to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine found [this project (Hopscotch)](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/), which accomplishes pretty much what I was looking for.  They also set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plainkeyman/JZqWF/) to demo some of the features for it.

The "tutorial" part of it can be configured like:

```
 {
    id: "welcome_tour",
    steps: [
      {
        target: "header",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "This is the navigation menu",
        content: "Use the links here to get around on our site!"
      },
      {
        target: "profile-pic",
        placement: "right",
        title: "Your profile picture",
        content: "Upload a profile picture here."
      },
      {
        target: "inbox",
        placement: "bottom",
        title: "Your inbox",
        content: "Messages from other users will appear here."
      }
    ]
  }
```

Users can be walked around your website using modals, which is what I was looking for.